# rails 4 : autocomplete with find or create by don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete, associations

I have a association one to many between jobs and companies and I have implemented the autocomplete features as mentioned in this railscast [enter link description here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised)

this is my job model

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :company

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :job_title, use: :slugged


      def company_name
        company.try(:name)
      end

      def company_name=(name)
        self.company = Company.find_or_create_by_name(name) if name.present?
      end

end
```

this is my company model

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :jobs

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

end
```

this is my jobs.js.coffe file

```
jQuery ->
  $('#job_company_name').autocomplete
    source: $('#job_company_name').data('autocomplete-source')
```

this is my job form view

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :company_name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :company_name, data: {autocomplete_source: Company.order(:name).map(&:name)} %>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :job_title, "Intitulé du poste", class: "jobs-newtitles" %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :job_title, class: "form-control form-newjob"  %>
    </div>
```

this is my job show view

```
        <div class="job-title-show">

            <h3><%= @job.job_title %></h3> 
            <div class="time_ago">
            Publiée  <%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(@job.created_at) %>
 <p>
          <strong>company:</strong>
             <%= @job.company_name %>
 </p>
        </div>
```

when i create a job and choose a company from the autocomplete liste or when i put a new company and go to the job show page the job is not affected to the company chosen or created why??

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a controller method for your autocomplete, add it to routes.rb and then reference that as the source, not call some method directly on the model in your view:

In your company_controller.rb:

```
def autocomplete_name
  @companies = Company.order(:name).where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { 
      render json: @companies.map(&:name)
    }
  end
end
```

I assume you're using jQuery UI's autocomplete, which supplies the word you're typing as a `term` param to whatever source is specified.

in your routes.rb:

`get '/companies/autocomplete/names' to: 'company#autocomplete_name'`

in this case your source would be `/companies/autocomplete/names.json`

Be sure to use your browser's console to debug this, to see if the AJAX call is being made to the right place and what not.

UPDATE: just saw the part with find_or_create_by_name, which seems really dangerous to combine with an autocomplete field. I would not recommend merging that action with autocomplete as you're likely to have users generate bunk data while typing things for search purposes.